# Map the id to its dateRange and return the result

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

```
List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
String cypher = "unwind $dateRanges as dateRange match(f:File)-[c:CHANGED]-(fo:Folder) where c.changedDate < dateRange.endDate and c.changedDate > dateRange.startDate return dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate, f, fo, $id as id"
neo4J.getResults(
    cypher,
    Values.parameters(
       "dateRanges", dateRangeMapList,
       "id", id.remove(0)
    ),
    results -> null
);


dateRangeMapList => [{startDate="2021-01-09", endDate="2021-01-15"},
{startDate="2021-01-15", endDate="2021-01-21"}]

id => ["123", "234"]
```

I need to point the "123" for the first dateRange in the dateRangeMapList and "234" to the second one. id.remove(0) always sets only the first id "123" to both the dateRanges. How to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Java expert, but as far as I understand the docs `ArrayList.remove()` returns the element that was removed from the list. So, `id.remove(0)` will return `123`. I don't understand why you are calling `id.remove(0)`.

You have 2 options:

(1) Put the corresponding id into the `dateRangeMapList`:

```sql
UNWIND $dateRanges AS dateRange
MATCH (f:File)-[c:CHANGED]-(fo:Folder)
WHERE c.changedDate < dateRange.endDate AND c.changedDate > dateRange.startDate 
RETURN dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate, f, fo,  dateRange.id AS id
```

```java
dateRangeMapList => [
  { id="123", startDate="2021-01-09", endDate="2021-01-15" },
  { id="234", startDate="2021-01-15", endDate="2021-01-21" }
]
```

(2) Iterate over both arrays like a for loop (avoid calling `id.remove(0)`):

```sql
UNWIND range(0, size($dateRanges)) AS index
MATCH (f:File)-[c:CHANGED]-(fo:Folder)
WHERE c.changedDate < $dateRanges[index].endDate AND c.changedDate > $dateRanges[index].startDate 
RETURN $dateRanges[index].startDate, $dateRanges[index].endDate, f, fo, $id[index] AS id
```

```java
dateRangeMapList => [
  { startDate="2021-01-09", endDate="2021-01-15" },
  { startDate="2021-01-15", endDate="2021-01-21" }
]
id => ["123", "234"]
```